# How do you use the Token Generation and Analysis tool in ZAP?

Tags: zap

In OWASP ZAP what does the summary in the Token Generation and Analysis tool mean?
What do each of the tests mean? There is not very much info about this tool online.

[ZAP Token Generation and Analysis tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWU9q.png)